# Using CalderaAI/Lazrus for CausalLM on a local server

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, large-language-model

I need to run a LLM on a local server and need to download different model to experiment.  I am trying to follow this guide from HuggingFace  https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#offline-mode

To begin with, I picked "CalderaAI/30B-Lazarus".  I ran the script

```
    from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
    model_name="CalderaAI/30B-Lazarus"
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
```

I got this message

```py
ValueError: Unrecognized configuration class <class 'transformers.models.llama.configuration_llama.LlamaConfig'> for this kind of AutoModel: AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.
Model type should be one of BartConfig, BigBirdPegasusConfig, BlenderbotConfig, BlenderbotSmallConfig, EncoderDecoderConfig, FSMTConfig, GPTSanJapaneseConfig, LEDConfig, LongT5Config, M2M100Config, MarianConfig, MBartConfig, MT5Config, MvpConfig, NllbMoeConfig, PegasusConfig, PegasusXConfig, PLBartConfig, ProphetNetConfig, SwitchTransformersConfig, T5Config, XLMProphetNetConfig.
```

Is it because AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM is not compatible with "CalderaAI/30B-Lazarus"?  If so, how do determine what is compatible for different model.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
 model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("CalderaAI/30B-Lazarus")
```